# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items selectlist .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Selectlist works perfectly for `Get` request .however for `Post` request it gives `null` exception

controller code:

```
var category = _context.CategoryTbl.ToList();
List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Category", Value = "0" });
foreach (var m in category)
{
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = m.Name, Value = m.Id.ToString() });
     ViewBag.category =li;
}
```

View code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(ViewBag.category, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "ddlCategory", style = "width: 200px;", @class = "form-control input-lg" })
```

I'm getting following error :

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

Comment: Can you please post the entire exception stack? Not just the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

1. It's more appropriate to store options as a property on your view model. This gets rid of the problems like this one with dynamics. It's much easier to track down problems when you remain strongly-typed.
2. You don't need to create a `SelectList`. All that's need is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which you already have.
3. It's preferable to use the `SelectTagHelper` here.

Taken together, on your model add:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryOptions { get; set; }
```

Then in your view:

```
<select asp-for="Category" asp-items="@Model.CategoryOptions"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related to your `POST` action where you also need a `ViewBag.category` if you return the same view.

You could either use the way in get method to initial it before return view, or simply use `new SelectList(_context.CategoryTbl, "Id", "Name")`,refer to below code:

```
[HttpPost]  
public async Task<IActionResult> MyPostMethodName(Model model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        //your post logic
        //...
        //need a  ViewBag.category if you return the same view,
        ViewBag.category = new SelectList(_context.CategoryTbl, "Id", "Name", model.Category);

        return View(product);
    }
```